# Intellij starting gradle multiple times and eventually fails

Tags: windows, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I am using Intellij on Windows to build a Ktor app, this problem is not specific to Ktor but any project, after about 30 mins or so of using the program and when I try to run the Application I am building, the log shows

- Starting Gradle Darmon
- Grade Daemon started in [x] seconds
- Starting Gradle Darmon
- Grade Daemon started in [x] seconds
  and so on...

Is there a way to resolve this, as of now the temporary solution is to restart my PC

[image]

Comment: Do you have NAT, Antivirus/Firewall running? See https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/12232#issuecomment-650770386

Comment: Actually no, I've posted the answer, I managed to identify the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seemed to be due to a WiFi hotspot turned on in my laptop, this seems to be a Gradle bug which will hopefully be fixed soon... I turned off the Hotspot and works fine....